# azure function outlook message webhook creator connector authenticate from dotnet core 2.0 app

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-functions

looking to use the microsoft graph webhook for mail messages

would like to authenticate against the outlook message webhook creator azure function for all users in an active directory application,

is this possible?

I am currently able to authenticate by using the /.auth/login/aad/ endpoint
with user consent

looking to do this with a client credential flow

or work it into an initial login for an asp.net core 2.0 application

working in postman I get an error message:
InvalidOperationException: The graph token has no scopes. Ensure your application is properly configured to access the Microsoft Graph.

I should have all the ms graph permissions set properly in the azure ad app registration.  I am trying to read each email that reaches an o365 inbox.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to look to Azure Logic apps. So you can have triggers and then you can store data to queue or blob storage

[Here is example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-office365-outlook) how you can do that

Comment: Can I do this on behalf of all users in the tenant?

Comment: @StephenDowd In Logic app there is action AD get users from group, Try to do loop over that and see if its possible to read their inbox.

Comment: Im also trying to do this in real time, so hoping to subscribe to the outlook webhook and refresh the subscription daily